# mediadecodec to SurfaceTexture: how onDrawFrame know outputBufferId

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I am using a surface texture as output of `mediacodec`, see some log below, 2 questions:

1. `mediacodec` released many times, why onFrameAvailable and onDrawFrame only be called once?
2. By calling `mSTexture.updateTexImage()` in `onDrawFrame`, `mSTexture` will be updated by one of many `mediacodec` output buffers released before, but I want to know the corresponding `outputBufferId` of the updated `mSTexture`, can i get that?

SurfaceTexture has function getTimestamp and getTransformMatrix, not sure if this can help, why getTimestamp always return 0 ?

`public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onDrawFrame");
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mUpdateST) {
            mUpdateST = false;
            mSTexture.updateTexImage();  // Here, I want to get the corresponding outputBufferId of the updated mSTexture
        }
}`

`public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onFrameAvailable");
    synchronized(this) {
        mUpdateST = true;
    }
}`

`public void onOutputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec mc, int outputBufferId, BufferInfo bufInfo) {
    Log.e(TAG, "OutputBufferAvailable " + outputBufferId);
    decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferId, true);
}`

E/ --- MainActivity -(19589): OutputBufferAvailable 15

E/ --- MainActivity -(19589): OutputBufferAvailable 14

E/ --- MainActivity -(19589): OutputBufferAvailable 13

E/ --- MainActivity -(19589): OutputBufferAvailable 12

E/ --- MainActivity -(19589): OutputBufferAvailable 11

E/ --- MyGLSurfaceView -(19589): onFrameAvailable

E/ --- MainActivity -(19589): OutputBufferAvailable 10

E/ --- MainActivity -(19589): OutputBufferAvailable 9

E/ --- MainActivity -(19589): OutputBufferAvailable 8

E/ --- MyGLSurfaceView -(19589): onDrawFrame

Answer (score 2):

SurfaceTexture operates in "asynchronous" mode.  Because the producer and consumer ends can be in the same process, this is useful to avoid deadlocks.  The practical effect of this is that SurfaceTexture will drop frames if you feed it too quickly.

If you look at `awaitNewImage()` in the [ExtractMpegFramesTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ExtractMpegFramesTest_egl14.java.txt), you can see how the decoder and the SurfaceTexture handler coordinate to process frames serially.

Ideally the presentation time stamp of the source material would propagate to the SurfaceTexture's timestamp.  Does the BufferInfo you get from `decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer()` have a nonzero timestamp?

Comment: will awaitNewImage slow down the decode speed? currently seems only 10fps

Comment: The performance bottleneck in ExtractMpegFramesTest is `bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, ...)`. Remove the compression and disk write, and it should run much faster. Of course, now it's not doing anything useful...